# How do I configure Warming Requests avoiding errors 404 on app's log?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have enabled [Warming Requests](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Warming%20_Requests) to my app, adding the following directive in `app.yaml`.

```
inbound_services:
- warmup
```

Looking at app's log I see several entries of this kind:

> 1.
>       01-05 02:49PM 50.037 /_ah/warmup 404 300ms 280cpu_ms 1kb
>       See details
>
> ```
> 0.1.0.3 - - [05/Jan/2011:05:49:50 -0800] "GET /_ah/warmup HTTP/1.1" 404 1188
> ```
>
> 2.
>       I 01-05 02:49PM 50.336
>
> This request caused a new process
>   to be started for your application,
>   and thus caused  your application code
>   to be loaded for the first time.
>   This request may thus take longerand
>   use more CPU than a typical request
>   for your application.

This makes sense because the *Warming Requests* documentation says:

> This causes the App Engine
>   infrastructure to issue GET requests
>   to /_ah/warmup. You can implement
>   handlers in this directory to perform
>   application-specific tasks, such as
>   pre-caching application data.

AFAIK `ah` is a [reserved URL](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Reserved_URLs), i.e. script handler and static file handler paths will never match these paths!

Should I simply add the `ah/warmup` route associating it to an empty web handler for example? Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Urls starting with `/_ah/` work just fine, despite what the documentation might lead you to believe.

So, yes, just map a handler to `/_ah/warmup` to make the warmup requests work.  I'm not sure how much benefit you'll get from using an empty handler, though.  Usually you'd want to import all of your important modules and do any cache warmups your app needs to be responsive.

Comment: See Nick Johnson (Google) answer here: http://code.google.com/appengine/forum/?place=topic%2Fgoogle-appengine%2Fx7vcuNK48Xg%2Fdiscussion

Comment: URLs under /_ah/ are reserved, which means you shouldn't use them for your own purposes, but there are several documented intended uses for those URLs, including warmup requests.