# Why does GAE spawn new instances even though I have set min idle=1 and pending latency=max?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a low/sporadic-load application and the latency caused by starting new instances (around 10s) far exceeds the time needed to process my requests, which typically complete in less than 500ms.

So in order to avoid the latency spikes caused by the spawning of new instances ("loading requests"), I made the following two settings:

- set min idle instances = max idle instances = 1, to ensure that there is always one instance running (one instance is enough to handle my traffic); and
- set the pending latency to 15s, so that GAE waits for up to 15s for the one resident instance to become free rather than start a new one.

Billing is activated. However, GAE still starts new instances resulting in inacceptable latency. Why is that?

In the logs I can see that my requests always return in less than 500ms; there is no way that a request would get queued up to 15s.

What can I do about this? Any help much appreciated.

**Update:** my solution was to set up a cron job which issues a request every 5 minutes, to always have a dynamic instance running. As it turned out (see answer below), idle instances are reserved for crazy load spikes, not the low-load scenario that I'm in 99% of the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @koma says, app-engine will create a dynamic instance to keep the number of idle instances constant, but not only it will create a new one but it will also use it immediately instead of using the idle one, on average. If you have a bunch of idle instances app engine will in fact still prefer spinning up dynamic ones even when a single request comes in, and will "save" the idle ones in case of crazy traffic spikes.

This is highly counter-intuitive because you'd expect it to use the instance that are already idling around to serve request and spin up dynamic ones for future requests, but that's not how it works.

Comment: **Many** thanks, this explains it. Can you refer me to any further info regarding the algorithm by which GAE decides whether to use the idle instances or spin up new dynamic ones?

Comment: @paul glad to hear it helped - unfortunately the algorithm in its detail is not public as far as I know, but this video (2nd part) should be helpful, it helped me a lot: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQ5_47zy4bY

Answer (score 0):

If you set min idle instances = 1, it will definitely spawn another instance at first request.... because there is no longer any idle instance (it is busy processing the first request !). 
And since a new instance is started, it might as well process some requests and be no longer idle ?

see also [Google App Engine Instances keep quickly shutting down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371920/google-app-engine-instances-keep-quickly-shutting-down)

Comment: That is not what's happening in my case: the request is _not_ processed by the (formerly) idle instance but by a newly spawned one, resulting in the high latency.